# JNINativeInterface_ * is null

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am developing a JNI application. However JNINativeInterface_ * inside the struct `struct JNIEnv_` is null, hence causing any call for JNI (example : `env->NewStringUTF(...)`) functions to throw a segmentation fault error. `JNIEnv_` struct looks like this :

```
struct JNIEnv_ {
    const struct JNINativeInterface_ *functions;
.
.
.
```

I honestly dont know how to fix this, as I think java is supposed to fill this when you make a call to `System.loadLibrary(...)`. I appreciate any help.

Comment: When you load the library in Java, JNI makes sure that a valid `env` to be provided.  You have to use the JNI that is provided to you in the native function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possibilities:

**1) Your C++ code is called from Java as native function:**

For example:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MyJNative_doSomething(JNIEnv *env, jobject jo)
{
    std::cout << "doSomething() : ";
}
```

The `JNIEnv*` pointer is given to you by the Java environment.

**2) Your C++ code calls the Java code via JNI:**

In this case you have to setup a `JavaVM*` and `JNIEnv*` pointer, following the JNI invocation logic.  See for example [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/993067/Calling-Java-from-Cplusplus-with-JNI).

A special case to be mentionned, if you have already invoked `JNIEnv*` but you work with multiple threads on C++ side.  Then every thread has to attach to the `JNIEnv*` using:

```
JNIEnv *env;                // Pointer to native interface
jint rc = jvm->AttachCurrentThread ((void **)&env, nullptr);  // Attach without addutiobal parameters
                            // where jvm is a valid JavaVM*
```

Comment: It is actually a mixture of the both. Java calls C++, registering C++ callbacks to an event in which some java methods will be ran. But as you have said, all these are done within other threads that are created within C++. This probably requires attachment as you have proposed ?

Comment: I would like to add that the jvm runs first, so I dont think i can create a new JVM in c++, that would not help. How could I get the existing jvm?

Comment: If the threads are created on Java side, the env received by C++ are the right ones.  If the threads are created in C++, you have indeed to attach them  to the jvm.  If you don't have the jvm, you can do:  `JavaVM* jvm;
env->GetJavaVM(&jvm);`

Comment: Is exporting `JNIEXPORT jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved)` a way to acquire javaVM, or am I better of just getting JavaVM from env and save it to a global C++ pointer of type `JavaVM` ?

Comment: Also, I cant quite grasp how those C++ threads cant access a globally saved JNIEnv pointer's address. Are the heaps separate or something ?

Comment: There is in fact [thread local storage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983875/what-does-the-thread-local-mean-in-c11) and here some more infos about [C++ threads in JNI context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642506/jni-attach-detach-thread-memory-management)